# How can we create custom-view same as dayGridMonth view in fullcalender (@fullcalendar/react)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

I want to create custom view same as **dayGridMonth** view in fullcalender. I'm using **@fullcalendar/react** plugin. I searched a lot of on google but not found any relative and useful information. they are providing custom-view for specific day layout. but I want to create new custom-view for daygridmonth view from scratch for specific day and months only.

I would appreciate if any help to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're aiming for... According to FC docs, "A DayGrid view is a view with one or more columns, each representing a day".
dayGridMonth is meant to be a "sub-type" of the daygrid view that always shows a whole month. You can create your own dayGrid view with the range you desire like this:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  header: {
    center: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridTenDays' // buttons for switching between views
  },
  views: {
    dayGridTenDays: {
      type: 'dayGrid',
      duration: { days: 10 },
      buttonText: '10 days'
    }
  }
});
```

That would show something like this:
[image: custom dayGrid, ten days]

Documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

Comment: I need this type of requirements. please review this attachment link : https://prnt.sc/13maien

Comment: On the month view, it is not possible to show an offset of days (10 days of one month and 20 of the next, for example). However, you can use `firstDay` option to have the first cell be whatever day of the week you want: 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, 2 - Tuesday, and so on.